# linux kernel source 2.6.34 : why could two function declarations of struct irq_desc *irq_to_desc(unsigned int irq) exist?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

[handle.c](https://github.com/shichao-an/linux/blob/v2.6.34/kernel/irq/handle.c)

I found two function declarations of struct irq_desc *irq_to_desc(unsigned int irq) in handle.c in linux kernel 2.6.43.

> `struct irq_desc *irq_to_desc(unsigned int irq) 
>   { 
>       return radix_tree_lookup(&irq_desc_tree, irq); 
>   }`

And

> `struct irq_desc *irq_to_desc(unsigned int irq)
>   {
>     return radix_tree_lookup(&irq_desc_tree, irq);
>   }`

They are in one file. But why could this file be compiled successfully ?

Comment: You have written the two functions identically above, but they have different function bodies in the real file. As Jose states in his answer, only one of them will be compiled, controlled by preprocessor conditionals.

Comment: It was never `2.6.43` kernel version of Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because one of them is defined in case of CONFIG_SPARSE_IRQ has been defined, else, the other.

Edit: Just one of them will be compiled